# Почему у ссылок не работает nth-child?

Tags: html, css

**1. Первый пример - все работает**

```css
.block > ul li:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <ul>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**2. Второй пример с ссылками - ничего не работает**

```css
.block > ul li a:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">text</a></li>
    <li><a href="">text</a></li>
    <li><a href="">text</a></li>
    <li><a href="">text</a></li>
    <li><a href="">text</a></li>
    <li><a href="">text</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: внутри тега li только один тег <а> , а Вы хотите взять 3-й . Ответ пользователя Ein Вам в помощь

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a:nth-child(3)` - это "элемент `а`, который является третьим дочерним элементом". Вам же нужно `li:nth-child(3) a` - "`а`, который находиться в `li`, который является третьим дочерним элементом"

```css
.block > ul li:nth-child(3) a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">text</a></li>
    <li><a href="">text</a></li>
    <li><a href="">text</a></li>
    <li><a href="">text</a></li>
    <li><a href="">text</a></li>
    <li><a href="">text</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```